# Simple PHP help needed

Tags: php

This is so simple, yet I cannot get my head into the logic.

Have a simple online form. Want to be able to adjust a variable after submitting.

If anyone can shed light on this one, would be really super appreciative!

```
$chocolatebar = $HTTP_POST_VARS['chocolatebar'];

if $chocolatebar = "a"  then we want to change the value to "snickers";

if $chocolatebar = "b"  then we want to change the value to "mars";

if $chocolatebar = "c"  then we want to change the value to "cherry ripe";
```

Comment: try $_POST instead of $HTTP_POST_VARS

Comment: Are you also looking for an explanation of the code?

Comment: Hi @asprin not really. Just a little help. I understand the logic just didn't have the syntax. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$chocolatebar = isset($_POST['chocolatebar']) ? $_POST['chocolatebar'] : '';
if ($chocolatebar == "a")  $chocolatebar = "snickers";
elseif ($chocolatebar == "b")  $chocolatebar = "mars";
elseif ($chocolatebar == "c")  $chocolatebar = "cherry ripe";
```

Comment: Thanks @sergey, worked a treat!

Comment: Why in the world would someone downvote this?

Comment: @asprin I downvoted this.

(i) i don't think it's good to use if instead of switch in cases like this.
(ii) you better write everything in `if(isset($_POST['chocolatebar']))` than doing 3 extra `if` checks even if variable is not set. This answer is too bad to be top/accepted.

Comment: Though you're right, but in this context it won't even matter much. Probably the project the OP is dealing with is not that big to worry about such things.

Comment: @asprin I wouldn't say anything if he did not check post variable, but he did it in wrong way. Also `switch` exists exactly for things like this and we should use it. Here is [[SO]], people learn here from each other and we must suggest better ways and cleaner code.

Comment: I'm all for getting to know better / alternative ways of doing things. But downvoting seems a bit harsh.

Answer (score 1):

```
$chocolatebar = $POST['chocolatebar'];

if($chocolatebar =="a")
{ 
     $chocolatebar="snickers";
}
else if($chocolatebar =="b")
{ 
    $chocolatebar="mars";
}
else
{ 
    $chocolatebar="cherry ripe";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all dont use `$HTTP_POST_VARS`, this function is deprecated [$HTTP_POST_VARS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Also, I guess you should use switch instead of if-else.

```
<?php
$chocolatebar = ($_POST['chocolatebar'] != '') ? $_POST['chocolatebar'] : '';

switch($chocolatebar){
    case 'a':
        $chocolatebar = 'snickers';
        break;

    case 'b':
        $chocolatebar = 'mars';
        break;

    case 'c':
        $chocolatebar = 'cherry ripe';
        break;

    default:
        $chocolatebar = '';
        break;
}

echo $chocolatebar;
```

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, when you have multiple options you better use [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) then multiple `if-else`.

```
if(isset($_POST['chocolatebar'])){
    $chocolatebar = $_POST['chocolatebar'];
    switch ($chocolatebar) {
        case "a":
            $chocolatebar = "snickers";
            break;
        case "b":
            $chocolatebar = "mars";
            break;
        case "c":
            $chocolatebar = "cherry ripe";
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$chocolatebar = $_POST['chocolatebar'];
switch($chocolaterbar){
    case "a": 
        $chocolatebar = "snickers";
    break;

    case "b": 
        $chocolatebar = "mars";
    break;

    case "c": 
        $chocolatebar = "cherry ripe";
    break;

    default:
        $chocolatebar = "unknown";
    break;
}
```

My purpose is to use switch. Or one other smart option is to use array..

```
$all_chocolates = array("a"=>"snickers","b"=>"mars","c"=>"cherry ripe");
$chocolatebar = $_POST['chocolatebar'];
$chocolatebar = isset($all_chocolates[$chocolatebar]) ? $all_chocolates[$chocolatebar] : "unknown";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use switch case if you want to change more value.

Comment: More of a comment than an answer

Answer (score 0):

For convenient, you will want a mapping between your keys to values.

```
$valueMap = array(
    'a' => 'snickers',
    'b' => 'mars',
    'c' => 'cherry ripe'
);

// The '@' sign prevents error if characters other than
// 'a', 'b', 'c' is provided, $value will be NULL in
// those cases.
$value = @$valueMap[$_POST['chocolatebar']];
```